# CSS topbar: vertical separator wraps the content of the bar

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, pseudo-element

I have made a site with a topbar in HTML and CSS. Now I wanted to add a vertical separator between some of the icons in the topbar, but it does not work.
First, when I added the separator-div it only displayed the first three icons but neither the separator nor the other icons.
Than I added `display: inline;` to the `#topbar` which made the separator and the other icons visible but below the topbar.
I also tried adding `white-space: nowrap;` to `#topbar` but it had no effect.

How can I make everything in the topbar being displayed in one line?

Here is the HTML and CSS:
https://jsfiddle.net/op28oohx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you expect?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gpkmm360/

Added `display: inline-block` to `topbar` and the `separator`

Comment: I tried but it says "You can't accept an answer in 2 minutes." But I will accept it in 2 minutes.